# jQuery plug-in not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I am now writing a web page using a bootstrap 3 template. When I include a jquery plugin ([jquery-frontier-calendar](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-frontier-calendar/)) in my page, I found that it does not work. I guess the problem is due to overlapping of javascript library.

For example, if I use the code below, the calendar works well but dropdown menu in my page not work.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/pageLogo.jpg">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/homepage/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/calendar/frontierCalendar/jquery-frontier-cal-1.3.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/calendar/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar/jquery-core/jquery-1.4.2-ie-fix.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar/lib/jshashtable-2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar/frontierCalendar/jquery-frontier-cal-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

*Dropdown menu*:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About us<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Company information</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**However**, if I add the below in the code, the dropdown menu work well but calendar cannot be displayed.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Could anyone help to fix this problem?????

Comment: Are you trying to include both jQuery 1.4.2 and jQuery 1.10.2 at the same page? The calender seems very outdated, find an updated version or use a more up to date one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try - `jQuery.noConflict();`

Check the usages in [jQuery website](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)